# Are there performance differences between GetComponent() or accessing a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I would like to access a component of a GameObject on trigger enter. I could use a `GetComponent<CustomClass>()`, or I could create at `Awake()` the connections of the GameObjects with the CustomClass in a Dictionary, so I can access the CustomClass as follows: `Dictionary[gameobject]`.

Are there any performance differences between the two?

Comment: This sounds like a case of `premature optimization`. Why do you care what is faster? You should only care about what suits your need for now. Once you notice a bottleneck, then it's time to `profile` and then finally to `optimize`.

Comment: @user2674389 You should `really` use `code block` for code, rather than for `emphasis` of non-code related items.  If you want to emphasize a word use *italics*.

Comment: @Servy Thank you, I try to keep it in mind. :-)

Comment: I agree that this is premature optimization, but why is this question closed? The question about "what is faster" is definitely not "opinion-based", you can run an experiment and determine the result.

Comment: @golergka The flag might be incorrect but the question should still be closed/held.  OP is just as capable as the rest of us in testing performance.  If not, that's a different question entirely.

Comment: @Jerdak in 90% of SO questions, API is as capable of the rest of us in reading documentation. I don't think it means that we should close all this questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.GetComponent()` for OnTriggerEnter should not be any issue :: the physics calculations of OnTriggerEnter would mostlikely be 10+ times as resource intensive

I would suggest saving optimizations like `Dictionary[Component]` for more repetitive tasks, like updating every AI script in your scene or increasing the mass of every rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) provides constant-time (in plain English: fast) lookups. Assuming it's not too much work to set up and keep up-to-date, it should be faster than [`GetComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), which is a more dynamic lookup.

However, I do wonder if this is a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).